# Subtractive Goldbach

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

In [this excellent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318193/3-primes-conjecture) it occurred to me that there is a subtractive Goldbach problem: Every even integer may be written as $p-q$ for primes $p,q$.

Does anyone have a reference for this problem?

Comment: I checked on my computer than this holds for ever even number up to 1984.

Comment: yeah this does not follow from Green-Tao.

Comment: @Pambos, that's great, the answer given by Harry Stern is perfect!